# How Do You Resize an Image in Python Using Pyglet

Tags: python, image, pyglet

I'm new to Pyglet (and stackoverflow) and cannot seem to find out how to resize images.

'pipe.png' is the image that I am trying to adjust the size of.

With this code, the image is not fully shown because the window size is too small.

I would like to adjust the size of the image so that it fits inside of the window.

The current size of 'pipe.png' is 100x576.

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

pyglet.resource.path = ["C:\\"]
pipe = pyglet.resource.image('pipe.png') 
pyglet.resource.reindex()  

@window.event                    
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    pipe.blit(0, 0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

**EDIT:**

I ended up finding out the answer here:

http://pyglet.org/doc-current/programming_guide/image.html#simple-image-blitting

The solution is:

```
imageWidth = 100
imageHeight = 100

imageName.width = imageWidth
imageName.height = imageHeight
```

This would adjust to image size to display as 100x100

Comment: It would be smashing if you kept aspect ratio ;)

Comment: I don't think your edit is the correct solution. According to my tests, your code would end up drawing just the bottom 100x100 of your image. Also, your link doesn't seem to point to the right page.

Answer (score 5):

Came across of this oldie, so for whoever lone ranger that ends up here juast as I did. Changing `.width` and `.height` won't do much in many cases (or at all these days?).

In order to successfully change a image resolution, you need to modify it's `.scale` attribute.

Here's a snippet of code that I use to resize a image:

```
from pyglet.gl import *

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

image = pyglet.image.load('test.png')
height, width = 800, 600 # Desired resolution

# the min() and max() mumbo jumbo is to honor the smallest requested resolution.
# this is because the smallest resolution given is the limit of say
# the window-size that the image will fit in, there for we can't honor
# the largest resolution or else the image will pop outside of the region.
image.scale = min(image.height, height)/max(image.height, height)), max(min(width, image.width)/max(width, image.width)

# Usually not needed, and should not be tampered with,
# but for a various bugs when using sprite-inheritance on a user-defined
# class, these values will need to be updated manually:
image.width = width
image.height = height
image.texture.width = width
image.texture.height = height
```

Comment: Is there any way to repeat the inside of an image this way? To clarify: I have an "image" for a platform (it is just two hollow rectangles at different heights) and I would like to be able to change the width of the image without scaling/stretching issues. Is there any way to do this (even using the raw image data) or would I have to use pyglet to draw the rectangles with openGL and forget the image?

Comment: @BeckettO'Brien I would draw a rectangle (and set the width) instead. Scaling images will almost always mean loss of data, and quality there after. So drawing primitives (rectangles, triangles and lines) are the way to go. Store them in a batch tho as they become very GPU/CPU intensive otherwise.

Comment: It looks like merely setting the width and height stretches the image to fit

Comment: `AttributeError: 'ImageData' object has no attribute 'scale'`

Comment: @Student the answer and post is from 2016. I'm pretty sure something might have changed in the library since then :)